# Can not get Hibernate to find data source

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

First post and new in the world of programming. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to have hibernate find my datasource. What am I doing wrong? If there is a better alternate way to accomplish this, let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.ronone.config;


import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.PathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DataConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        Resource config = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(config);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("opentalk.entity.package"));
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactory;


    }

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("opentalk.entity.package"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("opentalk.entity.package"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("opentalk.entity.package"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("opentalk.entity.package"));
        return dataSource;

    }
}
```

Here is my hibernate config.

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opentalk</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">open_talker</property>
        <property name="connection.username">ron</property>
        <property name="connection.passwod">metalgear3</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is Stack Tract

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/opentalk/target/classes:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.9/logback-core-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.4.0/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.6/jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.6/jackson-core-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6/commons-pool-1.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.ronone.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2017-03-31 06:14:26.975  INFO 2238 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 2238 (/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/opentalk/target/classes started by ronald in /Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/opentalk)
2017-03-31 06:14:26.978  INFO 2238 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-31 06:14:27.256  INFO 2238 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@23bb8443: startup date [Fri Mar 31 06:14:27 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-31 06:14:28.829  INFO 2238 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-31 06:14:28.916  INFO 2238 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-31 06:14:28.956  INFO 2238 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11ac1fa4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-31 06:14:29.446  INFO 2238 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-31 06:14:29.468  INFO 2238 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-03-31 06:14:29.470  INFO 2238 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-03-31 06:14:29.668  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-03-31 06:14:29.669  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2417 ms
2017-03-31 06:14:29.894  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-31 06:14:29.903  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-31 06:14:29.904  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-31 06:14:29.904  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-31 06:14:29.904  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-31 06:14:30.217  INFO 2238 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
2017-03-31 06:14:30.221  INFO 2238 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-03-31 06:14:30.470  INFO 2238 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-03-31 06:14:30.597  WARN 2238 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Not supported by BasicDataSource
2017-03-31 06:14:30.743  WARN 2238 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openTalkDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ronone/config/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2017-03-31 06:14:30.757  INFO 2238 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-31 06:14:30.771 ERROR 2238 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openTalkDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ronone/config/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.ronone.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ronone/config/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you pls post your stacktrace somewhere?

Comment: Added and thank you

Comment: Remove the `connection.*` properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Also why are you using plain hibernate instead of JPA with hibernate as the provider? And if yuo only have a single datasource I would suggest to let Spring Boot provide it for you. And you might want to set the `hibernate.dialect` property to the dialect of the database you are using. I also doubt that `env.getProperty("opentalk.entity.package")` is the correct property for all the datasource properties you are setting.